# How do I create a Gmail email draft in Python?

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap

I'm trying to create an email in Python that will appear in my Gmail drafts.

Here's my code:

```
from email.message import Message
import imaplib
import time

with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host="imap.gmail.com", port=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL_PORT) as imap_ssl:
    print("Logging into mailbox...")
    resp_code, response = imap_ssl.login('name@gmail.com', 'password key')

    # Create message
    message = Message()
    message["From"] = "You <me@example.com>"
    message["To"] = "recipient <someone@example.com"
    message["Subject"] = "This is a subject"
    message.set_payload("This is the email body")
    utf8_message = str(message).encode("utf-8")
    
    # Send message
    status, data = imap_ssl.append("[Gmail]/Drafts", "", imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), utf8_message)
    print(data)
```

The output is: `[b"[TRYCREATE] Folder doesn't exist. (Failure)"]`

I understand `[Gmail]/Drafts` is the issue, but I'm not sure what it should be instead?

N.B. The code will only be used with one email account so interoperability isn't a requirement.

**Update**

`imap_ssl.list()` returned, among other things, `b'(\\Drafts \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Google Mail]/Drafts"'`

When I try:

```
imap_ssl.append("[Google Mail]/Drafts", "", imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), utf8_message)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    status, data = imap_ssl.append("[Google Mail]/Drafts", "", imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), utf8_message)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/imaplib.py", line 417, in append
    return self._simple_command(name, mailbox, flags, date_time)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/imaplib.py", line 1055, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: APPEND command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

Comment: Can you try with the same `imap_ssl.append("[Gmail]/Drafts", "\Draft", imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), utf8_message)`(but with `\Draft` flag)?

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work with `"\Draft"` or `"\\Draft"`

Comment: Are you sure '[Gmail]/Drafts' is the name? I mean, for my gmail, it is '[Gmail]/Brouillons'. `[Gmail]/Drafts' wouldn't work. The name of the folder depends on the language when it was created (I don't really understand gmail logic, which is just exposing imap-like interface, but is not imap. But my understanding is that "draft" is a tag that is sticked onto folders whose name could be anything. So, aren't by any chance speaking another language than English that could be the one used for the naming of your draft folder?

Comment: Or, said otherwise, what is the output of `imap_ssl.list()`

Comment: Or even more acurately, of `[x for x in imap_ssl.list()[1] if b'Draft' in x]`

Comment: Note that the double quotes are part of the name (they are not python syntax, but are bytes of the bytestring). In my case, your code (with only change of username/password and name of draf folder) works, whether I include the `"` in the draft folder name or not. But in my case, there is no space in my draft folder name. And, double quotes, in many script languages, are what prevent spaces to to interpreted as argument separator... maybe it is the case for gmail server.

Comment: I would even say "probably". Why else would they include double quotes in the output of `.list()` (which is supposed to be read by client programs, not by a human user. So they consider that a piece of code needs to know there are double quotes in the folder name...)

Comment: So, in other words, what `imap_ssl.append(b'"[Google Mail]/Drafts"', "", imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), utf8_message)` gives?

Comment: Plus "could not parse command" is exactly the kind of message you would expect from a server, if, server side, because of an unquoted space in one of the arguments of a server-side command, one argument is interpreted as two. So `cmd` `[Google` `Mail]/Drafts` `other`, when it was expecting `cmd` `folderName` `other`. So, even if I can't be sure (because of my draft folder name having no space), I am quite confident that including double quotes is what is needed here.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for sharing your thinking so clearly. It really helped to understand the problem.